# How to get a reference to the view at the top of the NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am in a some UIViewControlle and need to go back to the previous one, I use this code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]);
// Here I need to reference to the view I am going go to to call some function before this view is being displayed
NSLog(@"Done button pressed");
```

But (as written in the comment), I need to get a reference to the view that will be displayed after the pop function executed (the previous viewController.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UINavigationController` property [topViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController) which gives you the view controller at the top of the stack.
Just call this before poping it, or it will be set to the next one :)

You can also access the `viewControllers` property to get all the viewcontrollers the navigation controller stack contains.

Comment: Both returns `(null)` if called after the `popViewController` function!

Comment: And what if you call it before calling poViewController _method_?

Comment: It returns current viewcontroller, but I need a ref to the previous viewController

Comment: use viewControllers, as I said, to access the whole navigation stack and get the n-2 view controller :)

Comment: `NSLog(@" count %i", [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]);` it returns ZERO!

Comment: Try to log the whole array, to see the result. And log self.navigationController also :) Because if you're calling it from the topViewController, after the pop was made, self.navigationController will return nil !

Comment: @Geoffroy - surely if he is on the top (or root) view, then the count should be `0` and `viewControllers` should contain the top/root view? Also `self.navigationController` should not be nil after the pop was carried out.

Comment: @MauriceKelly If the object isn't anymore in the navigation stack, then it navigationController property should be nil, as it belongs to no navigation controller. And the count is 0 if there is only a root view controller? What a strange behavior

Comment: @Geoffroy Sorry! My mistake - when I said count of 0, I was thinking of the index being 0! Also forgot that the `self` is the view controller that has just been popped off. Having an off night obviously!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `viewControllers` property in the [online docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers). It will give you an array of view controllers in the navigation stack:

> The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

So the view controller you want will be at index `n-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what @Geoffroy and @Maurice Kelly said..

I should get reference to the object before calling the `popViewControllerAnimated:`  function

```
  // I should get reference to the object here before calling the popViewControllerAnimated:  function
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]);
    NSLog(@"Done button pressed");
```

Comment: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` returns a reference to the view controller that you have just discarded. This is not what you asked for in your original question: *"the view that will be displayed after the pop function executed"*